# Excel - Need to check cell values against array and create concatenated list from secondary column

Tags: excel-formula

This isn't super complex, but it's got a bunch of moving parts and I'm struggling to put them all together.  Have tried various fixes and solutions but can't make it work.

PROBLEM

I've got a list of values.  I want to take those values (individually), look for them in a separate array, and if a match is found take the value of the cell NEXT to the match and concatenate all values in one cell.

Here's a quick example

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCd2I.png]

Basically I want to dynamically populate column B.  To do this I need to take the ref values in column A, look for each of them in the list of "Favorite Fruits", and when found grab the name in the column next to it and concatenate the names with commas in a single field.

Thoughts?  Like I said, it's not a tough problem, just a lot of moving pieces (which I guess makes it a tough problem). Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!
Rick

Comment: I'm having a tough time just visualizing what you are describing. Can you do a screenshot of whta you have and what you want it to look like?

Comment: Sorry, can't figure out where to host it and no where here to put it.  Let me update my post and see if that clears things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in Cell `B2`:
`=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF($D$2:$D$15=A2, $E$2:$E$15,""))` make sure and lock it in as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then drag/copy down to populate each needed cell.

Comment: Even better!  Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. It was my first time using the formula so I learned something too.

Answer (score 0):

B2Formula:   {=CONCAT(IF(A2=$D$2:$D$15,$E$2:$E$15 & ",",""))}

Introduce with ctrl+shift+Enter to make it matricial formula "{=Formula}" after that just drag the formula.

Comment: Works awesome!  Thanks a bunch.  The only issue is that I'd like to be able to avoid ending with a comma, and not to include one if there's only one entry.  Any idea how I modify the last part to only add the comma between two entries when it's more than one?  Also, it's weird, I put some text in the last set of quotes (the else part) but it wouldn't show it (broke the formula).  But other than that great stuff, and super simple.  Thanks!